# Using variables in tikz node labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

Is it possible to define variables in LaTeX file and use the variable names in the tikz labels?

I have a network diagram, that I want to create a table of IPs at the beginning of the file instead editing each node in the latex file.  The network diagram is generic and I will change the IPs often.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

def nameIP1 10.0.0.1
def nameIP2 192.168.0.1

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[block] (nodeIP1) { nameIP1 };
\node[block] (nodeIP2) { nameIP2 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Normal macros can be used. Macro names cannot easily use numbers, therefore the example uses `A` and `B` instead of `1` and `2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\newcommand*{\nameIPA}{10.0.0.1}
\newcommand*{\nameIPB}{192.168.0.1}

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[block] (nodeIP1) {\nameIPA};
\node[block] at (0, -1) (nodeIP2) {\nameIPB};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You can define a style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={rectangle, draw},
  nameIP1/.style={node contents=10.0.0.1},
  nameIP2/.style={node contents=192.168.0.1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node [block,nameIP1] {};
\path (0,1) node [block,nameIP2] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]